# catch packets on an ip interface in Python

Tags: python, linux, sockets, listener

I would like to know if there's a simple way in python to create a listener that intercepts UDP or TCP packets on my local machine.
Maybe my question is a bit unclear, but I myself don't know much about networks.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). This is a tool for packet manipulation and interception for Python on *nix systems.